# How to simulate an NSData object in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, type-conversion

I would like to know about the way by which I can go around and convert between an NSData object (for example a UIImage encoded as such) and its equivalent in C++ and vice versa.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily even need to resort to C++.  Data storage can be done with simple `void*`'s, or even `const char *`'s

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector<byte>` is the closest equivalent, I think. But the equivalence is a bit loose. It's just that they're both used to hold sequences of arbitrary bytes.

It is hard to see why you'd really want to do this, though. Like CodaFi said, if you just have to pass the object through some C++ code, as long as it's being retained in Objective-C-land, you can just use a void pointer. It's not like C++ could generally deal with a serialized Objective-C object anyway.

Comment: I can go with void *. No serialization needed. How do I do this? For example I want my struct to hold a pointer to an object held initially by a UIImage.

Comment: @AldrichCo: You just use a variable of type `void *`. A void pointer is essentially just a pointer value with no type information, so you can assign anything to it.